# Possible to query embedded realm objects directly on Android/Java?

Tags: java, android, realm

I migrated my Android app to Realm 10 recently in order to use the new **embedded** object functionalities (mainly cascade deleting). So, according to the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/android/embedded-objects/): "It is **not possible to query embedded objects directly**. Instead, access embedded objects through a query for the parent object type."

However, I was able to migrate some of my realm objects to embedded without changing any queries and I don't get any compilation errors, nor failing queries or crashes, even though I have queries in my code where I retrieve (now) embedded objects directly. At the same time, on the iOS counterpart of the projects when the same realm objects where migrated to **embedded** those same queries were no longer compiling and needed to be reworked.

So my questions are:

1. Have I misunderstood the documentation on that specific part?
2. Is there an error in the documentation on that specific part?
3. Is the "not possible to query embedded objects directly" part something that will be added soon and will prevent my app from working correctly in the future?

Here is an example from my project of a working query accessing and embedded object directly:

```
AddressDbm address = realm.where(AddressDbm.class)
            .equalTo("contacts.contactId", contactId)
            .equalTo("contacts.firstName", firstName)
            .equalTo("contacts.lastName", lastName)
            .findFirst();
```

and the corresponding realm objects:

```
@RealmClass(embedded = true)
public class ContactDbm extends RealmObject {
    //some properties 
    private String contactId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // list property of type embedded object
    RealmList<AddressDbm> addresses;
}

@RealmClass(embedded = true)
public class AddressDbm extends RealmObject {
    //some properties 
    private String streetName;

    // Reverse relationship to parent object
    @LinkingObjects("addresses")
    private final RealmResults<ContactDbm> contacts = null;
}
```

I even tried a query without using the reverse relationships and it still works, e.g.:

```
AddressDbm address = realm.where(AddressDbm.class)
            .equalTo("streetName", "Washington blvd.")
            .findFirst();
```